# I need to save the data that I edit, but it just makes it empty and nothing is saved

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page on which there are pictures of hotels and their description, there is a button to create and there should be editing, how can I do it on JavaScript. I have created a form and all the buttons, but when I click on save editing, it does not work and makes my hotel look bad. This is m

```
editSubmitButton.addEventListener("click", handleEditHotel);

function handleEditHotel() {
  if (hotelToEdit) {
    const { name, location, rooms, rating } = getInputValues();
    hotelToEdit.name = name;
    hotelToEdit.location = location;
    hotelToEdit.rooms = rooms;
    hotelToEdit.rating = rating;

    // Сховайте форму для редагування після збереження змін
    editForm.style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("add_form").style.display = "block";

    clearInputs();
    renderItemsList(hotels);
    saveDataToLocalStorage();

    hotelToEdit = null;
  }
}
function handleCancelEdit() {
  editForm.style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("add_form").style.display = "block";
  clearInputs();

  hotelToEdit = null;
}

cancelEditButton.addEventListener("click", handleCancelEdit);
```

I need to fix the code so that the button works correctly and the changes I edit are saved

Comment: *it does not work* isn't particularly helpful. What are you expecting to do and what is it doing instead? What have you done to debug this? You should include a minimal reproducible example so we can have the full picture. For example, we would need to know what the html includes and what all your functions called here do.

Comment: hotelToEdit is not defined

Comment: Your question title and description don't seem to match. Please edit your question and clearly explain what you are trying to do, what exactly is happening now, and what your specific question is.